# If two divs contain identical text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write something that compares the text between two divs.

```
Example: 
<div class="section-a">Hello World</div>
<div class="section-b">Hello World</div>
```

If the text from both section-a and section-b are identical, do something...
Do I run a comparison using .html()?

Comment: "Do I run a comparison using .html()". You can, yes. Or `.text()`. Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
if ( $(".section-a").text() == $(".section-b").text() ) {
console.log("same");
}
```

Comment: No need to use === strict comparison, both values are returned from .text() as the same variable type (string).

Comment: @SetSailMedia .text() always returns string.  I missed it.  Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: No mistake, just more info for you :}

Comment: Thanks. I'm well on my way to solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare using `.text()` which will strip all HTML formatting.

```
if ( $(".section-a").text() == $(".section-b").text() ) {
// do something
}
```